# WinJS load configuration data on startup

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, winjs, windows-store-apps

I am working on an app for the windows store using HTML/CSS/JS and the WinJS framework.

My app needs to load configuration data on startup, either over the network if online or locally if not.

My problem is that ideally the app should just display the splash screen with a progress control, until the data has been loaded. But I no clue where to put my loading code to accomplish that.

I could do something like this:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.Binding.optimizeBindingReferences = true;

    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
    var nav = WinJS.Navigation;

    function loadConfig() {
        return WinJS.xhr({ url: myURL }).then(
            function (xhr) {
                // parse response stuff
            },
            function (xhr) {
                // do error handling stuff
            }
        );
    }

    function initializeUI(args) {
        // The generated code for setting up the navigation controller, but moved to a seperate function
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {
            if (nav.location) {
                nav.history.current.initialPlaceholder = true;
                return nav.navigate(nav.location, nav.state);
            } else {
                return nav.navigate(Application.navigator.home);
            }
        }));
    }

    app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {

                loadConfig().then(
                    function () {
                        initializeUI(args);
                    }
                );
            } 
            if (app.sessionState.history) {
                nav.history = app.sessionState.history;
            }
            if ( config ) // check if configuration exists to prevent calling this twice
                initializeUI(args)
        }
    };
    app.start();
})();
```

But that would display my "default.html" page until the data is loaded, so I'd have to use my splash image in "default.html" and insert a progress control.

That doesn't feel like the correct solution for my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution looks fine. You should look at the [extended splash screen sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Splash-screen-sample-89c1dc78) to get the right feel for setting up the extended splash screen so it's seamless.

What don't you think feels right?

One other suggested tweak: Change your loadConfig call, to always return a promise, even if the data is stored locally; that way, your code can flow the same way and you never need your

```
if(config) {
    initializeUI(args);
}
```

code.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I don't like the fact that I have to style "default.html" like the splash screen, I think I was hoping I could somehow tab into the booting process. But if you say it's fine I'll take your word for it :) - I'll take a look at your link when I get back on my Win8 machine after the weekend (for some reason the "browse code" option doesn't seem to work). Thanks again.

Comment: There are some options; you've already deferred it, so that gives you more time. You don't have to style the whole file; just add one element that's positioned absolute. In my app, I just remove that element when I'm complete. Makes it nice and clean.